# iPhone UITableView paginate results

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pagination

What us the best way to paginate a large number of results that are being pulled from a sever?  As far as the server goes, I can offset and limit the results so I'm only pulling maybe 25 at a time, but what's the best way to allow a user to view more results without constantly scrolling down a growing list like the app store app?

thanks,
Howie

Answer (score 5):

To add a new cell at the bottom of your list that will get the next set when you click it, do the following

In the ...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

Add 1 extra row if there is more to retrieve

```
  return totalCount > [list count]?[list count]+1:[list count]
```

Then for the last cell in ...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

create the 'Load more' cell if it's required

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoadMoreCell" owner:self options:nil];
LoadMoreCell *cell = loadMoreCell;
NSString *loadMore = [NSString string with Format:@"Load %d more...", numberToLoad];
```

Then in ...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

do what is required to update the list of items in the tableview with the new amount

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I was actually looking for an alternative solution so the tableview doesn't have to keep growing.

Comment: I'm curious @Ward if you've come up with anything because I dont' think I've ever seen that type of user experience in an iPhone app before.