# Add rows dynamically to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an app that fetches some messages from a web service that returns them by pages. I am displaying the first page initially, but if the user wants to scroll down and see past messages, I am supposed to make the request for the next page and get the messages. My question is, what's the best way to expand the Table View and add the messages to the data source and load them in the table so the user can see them?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to provide placeholders immediately so that the user can scroll, and then get the messages in a background thread and then come back to the main thread and reload the table.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone UITableView paginate results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690936/iphone-uitableview-paginate-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 'load more' section with one row in it. Place an activity indicator in it. In 'cellForItem' for this section make a request and reloadData once you receive the data.

Comment: Very close to what I am doing at the moment. Though reloading the whole tableview isn't that efficient. It shows a lot of scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect when the table view is near the bottom. Make a request for more data and then load it into the tableview's data source. (Array or whatever you're using) then you just reload the tableview. Row count can be the datasource you're using.

I do this often in my app.

Comment: I thought about this, but it came to my mind that reloading the whole table every time isn't very efficient. I also looked in the documentation and found some methods used to update the table (self.tableView beginUpdates and endUpdates or something like that and insertRows at indexPath).

The point is, I don't know what's the best way to do this.

Comment: I'll concede that my method isn't all that efficient and could be improved. When I get some time, I'll investigate a better way of doing it. If you come across an effecting way of doing this, I'd be interested in exploring it with you.

Comment: I came across this article that uses this method http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/02/dynamically-loading-new-rows-into-a-table.html

Give me an email at alexandru.clapa@gmail.com and I'll gladly accept to further research with you an efficient way.

Comment: I'm using this method in production and it works very smoothly, I wouldn't try to investigate further unless you are actually experiencing a performance hit.

Comment: While that blog does a good job, it require the user to tap a button / cell for more data. I prefer just scrolling. When my tableview gets the the bottom, I display a loading cell and fetch more data and the user knows the app is fetching more data. I find this gives a better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the UIScrollView delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll`, and check whether the table has been scrolled close to the bottom, and then update your array that helps the datasource methods popular the table view, and call `reloadData`:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    DLog(@"Did scroll: contentOffsetY: %f, contentHeight:%f", scrollView.contentOffset.y, scrollView.contentSize.height);

    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        // update your datasource/array that provides content to table view
        [yourTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```